# iPhone setIdleTimerDisabled can't be turned off

Tags: ios, iphone, timer, locking, screen

iOS developers, has anybody seen what I've recently seen:
I'm building an universal app on iPhone and iPad. Programmatically, I try to prevent screen lock by setting

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled: YES];

after a while when I call:

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled: NO];

It doesn't work on iPhone (won't go idle and shut off screen) but iPad seems fine. Strange?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: + when quit the app and just test it out on the home screen, the phone is able to lock the screen itself

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bummer, here's the reason that I just found - it works once you disconnect the device from XCode. XCode debugging is the culprit.